# SeleniumBasic and Controlling Existing Edge Browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, microsoft-edge

For the past few months, I have been using SeleniumBasic with Excel and Microsoft Edge and have created some pretty useful macros for our company.

The problem I can’t seem to solve is being able to control an existing Edge/Chrome browser window that’s already open thru Excel/VisualBasic.

I have done quite a bit of searching and have found a few existing discussions regarding this subject. From what I have read and gathered, what I am trying to do is impossible with SeleniumBasic. However, there is no explanation as to why this is.

Is this just a limitation of SeleniumBasic? I understand it is fairly outdated and hasn’t been updated in a while. I know there’s code in python and java that allows you to extract existing session id through Selenium, and controlling an already open browser instance can be achieved.

I guess ultimately what I’m trying to figure out is if there is any way at all to incorporate into an excel macro coding that would allow control of an existing browser session (Chrome/Edge). Are there alternatives to SeleniumBasic that would allow me to achieve this?

Presently, my macro opens a new instance of Edge, goes to a specific website for our company (which requires login and 2FA), then once logged in, takes the data in the excel sheet and inputs the data into the site. The big annoyance here is the logging in/2FA part. Every time the macro is run, have to redo 2FA and takes up a bunch of time. Ideally would love to login just once, do the 2FA and proceed with the macro.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions? Am I just SOL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control an existing browser through SeleniumBasic.

From your description, I think you can open the browser with a specific profile as a workaround. For example, you can remember the login information in a profile, every time you open the website using that profile, it will login automatically.

To open browser with specific profile, you can refer to the following code (I test it only works with Chrome):

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    'If you use the Default profile, you only need to set user-data-dir. Change the UserName to your owns
    driver.AddArgument ("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
    'If you use other profile, you need to set profile-directory with profile folder name
    'driver.AddArgument ("profile-directory=Profile 1")
    driver.Get "https://www.google.com"
    driver.Wait 3000
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @aim007 Is there any update about the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.